# Re-size all images in directory with PHP?

Tags: php, glob

I'm doing some web development I would like to resize all images in a directory using PHP. The directory is public property, and anyone working on the site can insert images (to be used as a random background). Is there a way to check the size of the image that's selected from the array of filenames using PHP? And furthermore, could you cast the image to a particular size if the parameters are too large?

```
<?php

$bg = glob("imgfiles/*.*"); $add image names to array
$i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
$selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set background equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
```

Comment: good start, now run a resize function inside a loop http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+image+resize

Comment: Can you add to your PHP the Imagick extension? https://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: I'd have to ask my boss. Would that provide a relatively simple solution?

Comment: @Dagon the thing is I know how to resize an image with PHP using a resize function but I'm not sure how I'd implement that AND glob at the same time.

Comment: is this any help: `foreach($bg as $MY_FILE){ resize_function($MY_FILE);}`

Comment: Btw, `$selectedBg = $bg[array_rand($bg)];` :)

Comment: @Dagon it might be, the tricky part is setting it up so the image only resizes if it's too large. The function has to be entirely dynamic, and I don't want to upscale images; I only want the image to be made smaller if it's too big.

Comment: What Image tools are you using? GD?

Comment: check the size in the function (if greater than x resize else dont). this question is moving all over the place. how about some code and a SPECIFIC question

Comment: @Dagon I edited the question to be more specific. I want to be able to check the size of the randomly selected file, and then scale the image if required. I know how to resize a preselected image; I have no clue as to how I'd go about doing it in this scenario.

Comment: @Twisty I'm not really using any image tools, just whatever the php server has installed

Comment: imagesize>>>http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: you have all the tools, just put them together!

Comment: Oh and if you're using this in production, I will send an invoice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would suggest something like:

```
<?php
$maxw = 1024;
$maxh = 320;
$bg = glob("./imgfiles/*.*");  // add image names to array
$selectedBgPath = "./imgfiles/" . $bg[array_rand($bg)]; // set background path equal to which random filename was chosen
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($selectedBgPath);
if($width > $maxw || $height > $maxh){
  // Resize as needed
  // $newSelectedBgPath
}
if(isset($newSelectedBgPath)){
  $fp = fopen($newSelectedBgPath, "rb");
} else {
  $fp = fopen($selectedBgPath, "rb");
}
header("Content-type: $type");
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: it worked! thank you! I had to make a few small adjustments but for the most part this works :)

Comment: size the resized image, dont resize on the fly